# "No Carrier" when I make AT call from Modem

Tags: gsm, at-command

I am trying to make calls and send texts from the GSM modem, but when I try to make a call it says "No Carrier"  I cant seem to fix the problem or figure out what is wrong.  Please help me trouble shoot the problem!!

```
at+cnum
+CNUM: "","16108647718",129,7,4

OK
AT+COPS=?
+COPS: (2,"T-Mobile ","T-Mobile ","310260"),(1,"AT&T","AT&T","310410"),,(0-4),(0-2)

OK
ATD 6107938274;
OK

NO CARRIER
```

Comment: What does the AT+CREG command return when you execute it?

Comment: AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,0

OK                                                                                                             I think this means it is not connected to a service provider, even though the SIM is live, but I am not sure how to fix this problem

Comment: Right, it's not auto searching. Try AT+COPS=0 and then check with AT+COPS? or AT+CREG to see if it subscribed to an operator.

Comment: I tried using the command you suggested, but it says error.  Should it have a second parameter, like 0,0?

Comment: Thank you for your help aldridmc...it turns out my SIMs were fine, but this particular modem needs tmobil.  Anyway, it works now and thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SIM is for which operator? Suppose it is for T-mobile, you can try

at+cops=1, 2, "310260"

If it failed, then you may try with

at+cops=0

My guess is your modem is keeping some wrong information about the operator...